# How to get the width of a word in a dynamic textfield?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I have a dynamic textfield that gets filled with a random word and I would like to add an add the end of the word with a 10px space in between.
How to get the word width in the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextField class has `textWidth` property. Use this property to get the width of the word in a dynamic TextField.